# Background invisible when masking in an FBO

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am trying to mask a foreground texture onto a background texture in  LibGDX. It works fine when drawing to the screen, but when drawing in an FBO the background disappears.

[image]

Here is how the masks are drawn:

```
batch.draw(background, x, y);
batch.flush();

Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO);
batch.draw(mask, x, y);
batch.flush();

Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
batch.draw(foreground, x, y);
batch.flush();

batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Here is how I am drawing the regular one, and the FBO one:

**Regular**

```
batch.begin();
batch.enableBlending();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

drawFull(32, 600 - (64 * 4) - 32);

batch.end();
```

**FBO**

```
// draw the FB mask

fb.begin();
batch.begin();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(fbcamera.combined);
batch.enableBlending();

Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

drawFull(0, 0);

batch.end();
fb.end();

// draw the FB mask to the main batch

batch.begin();
batch.enableBlending();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

batch.draw(fb.getColorBufferTexture(), 32, 600 - (64 * 7) - 32);

batch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by disabling blending when drawing the FBO to the screen. This comes at the disadvantage that we can not draw the FBO with opacity.

```
// draw the FB mask to the main batch

batch.begin();
batch.disableBlending();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

batch.draw(fb.getColorBufferTexture(), 32, 600 - (64 * 7) - 32);

batch.end();
```

[image]